# Use administration theme for verified users when adding or editing content

Tags: 7, theming

I'm having a problem with the administatration theme. I want verified users to see the administration theme when they are adding or editing content. Right now only the admin user sees the administration theme and verified users see the standard theme. Is it possible to also enable this for verified users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable **`View the administration theme`** permission for verified/authenticated users.

[image]